# Website not accessible on ceretain ISP's

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server

When i attempt to load my website i receive the following error..

“Unable to determine IP address from host name for www.carehomesinleeds.co.uk“

Yet it can be accessed on my friends ISP and the host is also saying it’s up.

How do I troubleshoot and resolve this issue.

I have tried tracert and it just tells me that the hostname cannot be resolved.

All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set your DNS to use on your work station / laptop.

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

Else try / use the tool dnstrace to help you debug (Hoping you a Linux user of course ;) )